# Is it possible to have only one comparison per iteration of a binary search algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, micro-optimization

In binary search algorithm we have two comparisons:

```
if (key == a[mid]) then found;

else if (key < a[mid]) then binary_search(a[],left,mid-1);
      else binary_search(a[],mid+1,right);
```

Is there a way by which I can have only one comparison instead of the above two.

--

Thanks

Alok.Kr.

Comment: As always: do you need to obscure the algorithm for performance? Is this in the critical code path? Is the performance of this specific method affecting the performance of the overall program? Is it due to the extra comparison? My bet is that the extra comparison is having no effect overall in the program runtime. If you really need to optimize the algorithm, meassure first, then think about what you are doing. I bet that changing from recursive to iterative will a) make it less readable (so only do it if really needed) and b) improve the runtime speed much more than the comparison.

Comment: @David: In this case, it seems like an important academic question to know, and applying the optimization makes the algorithm more canonical.

Comment: @ David :I just wanted to know that if it is possible irrespective of the optimization or complexity.

@ Potatoswatter : The question was asked in once in Adobe placement papers. So I just wanted to know if it is possible. I have now also posted one possible solution by myself, but still curious.

Thanks
Alok.Kr.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Single_comparison_per_iteration

Taken from wiki:

```
   low = 0
   high = N
   while (low < high) {
       mid = low + ((high - low) / 2)
       if (A[mid] < value)
           low = mid + 1;
       else
            //can't be high = mid-1: here A[mid] >= value,
            //so high can't be < mid if A[mid] == value
            high = mid;
   }
   // high == low, using high or low depends on taste
   if ((low < N) && (A[low] == value))
       return low // found
   else
       return -1 // not found
```

**Pros/cons from wiki:**
"This approach foregoes the possibility of early termination on discovery of a match, thus successful searches have log2(N) iterations instead of an expected log2(N) − 1 iterations. On the other hand, this implementation makes fewer comparisons: log2(N) is less than the expected number of comparisons for the two-test implementations of 1·5(log2(N) − 1), for N greater than eight."

Comment: I like that the linked article states pros/cons of this technique.

Comment: Why high index is necessarily N instead of N-1. and while finding mid index, why should it point to first element in second half rather than last element in first step, any specific reason behind?  @LasseEspeholt

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Just don't eliminate `mid` from the recursive call.

```
if ( left == right ) return NULL;
if ( left + 1 == right ) return key == a[left]? &a[left] : NULL;

mid = left + ( right - left / 2 );

if (key < a[mid]) return binary_search(a[],left,mid-1);
else return binary_search(a[],mid,right); // include `mid` in next round
```

You only need to eliminate half of the set with each recursion to achieve O(logN) performance. You're going above and beyond by eliminating half+1.

If you only use `<` during recursion, the algorithm will find the least element which is not less than `key` (but may be greater than `key`). Finish off by performing a single equality test.

Comment: Wouldn't you need another comparison (pre recursive call) to determine whether you're down to a single element and decide to perform the final equality test?

Comment: @Damien: yep, I added that as you commented. But that test is not a *key* comparison, it's an index comparison, which presumably has simpler computational complexity.

Answer (score 2):

In assembler, you could:

```
cmp key,a[mid]
beq found
bge else
```

So if your compiler is really good at peephole optimizations, it might already do this for you.

Comment: The compiler will probably do this because peepholes are something you can take for granted… anyway, the difference is insignificant. The question is important anyway, since it applies to cases where the comparison is an expensive function.

Comment: If the comparison is expensive, create a function which returns the sign of the comparison so you can examine the sign several times.

Comment: That's not an option in C++, where the search is performed by a generic function which requires a `bool` typed functor.

Comment: If you want to optimize the performance here, you must widen the API. If you can't, then you can't improve the performance. Chose your poison, please :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is recursive algorithm. First comparison is stop criteria and second actual search, so you cannot remove them.

In first you asking whenever you have already found the element and in second in which part of the array to look for element. So you cannot make those decisions based only on one comparison.

Comment: He can create a function that compares `key` and `mid[a]` and returns the sign of the comparison (an `int`). Comparing this `int` with fixed values (`-1`, `0` or `1`) will cost less (or at worst, as much) as comparing `key` and `mid[a]`, depending on what `key` and `mid[a]` are.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: do you need to optimize the program? Have you measured to know where you need to do it? Is it in this function?

For primitive types the second comparison is as fast an operation as it gets. The higher cost of the comparison is loading the element into the appropriate register, and that is needed for the first comparison. Once that comparison is executed, the value is already in a register and the second operation takes a single processor instruction plus the possible cost of the branch misprediction.

Assuming integral types, the cost in processor time of the algorithm is most probably dominated by the cost of the recursive calls if the compiler is not being able to perform tail-recursion optimization. If you really need to optimize this, try compiling with all the optimization flags on and analyze the assembler to identify whether the tail-recursion optimization is being applied. If not, manually convert the algorithm from recursive to iterative.

This will have two effects: obscure the code (avoid modifying a clean solution unless you really need to) and it avoid function calls.

If you are speaking of C++, and the type is complex and the overloaded comparison operators are expensive, the fastest boost in performance is implementing a `compare` method that will return a negative number for *less-than*, `0` for equal, and a positive number if *greater-than*. Then precompute the result before the comparisons and then perform integer only checks. That will remove the overall cost of the algorithm to a single processing of the real objects with the expensive comparison and set you back in the original assumption.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (step = 0; step < n; step <<= 1);

for (i = 0; step; step >>= 1)
    if (i + step < n && v[i + step] <= x)
        i += step;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was a interview question in Adobe, and I was just trying to figure out how to do this.

Now I have got solution to it, so I,m posting

```
void binary_search (int a[] , int low ,  int high , int key )
{
    int mid = (low+high)/2;

    if (key == a[mid]) {
        printf ("Number Found\n");
        return;
    }

    else {
        int sign = Calc_sign (key-a[mid]);
        low = low*sign + (1-sign)*mid;
        high = mid*sign + (1-sign)*right;
        binary_search (a,low,high,key);
    }
}

int Calc_sign(int a) 
{
     return ( (a & 80000000) >> 31);
}
```

So in the code there will only be one comparison for checking if the keyvalue is eqaul to the mid element.

--

Thanks

Alok Kr.

Comment: A possible problem with such math-based comparisons (`key-a[mid]`) is that they could underflow. Plus it only works with numeric types.